Solution of this error without --force or --legacy-peer-deps
Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm error
npm error While resolving: shopping-cart@0.1.0
npm error Found: react@19.0.0
npm error node_modules/react
npm error   react@"^19.0.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0
npm error node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm error   @testing-library/react@"^13.0.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm error
npm error
npm error For a full report see:
npm error C:\Users\Krishna\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-12-06T06_18_52_109Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Krishna\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-12-06T06_18_52_109Z-debug-0.log
npm error C:\Users\Krishna\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-12-06T06_18_52_109Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Krishna\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-12-06T06_18_52_109Z-debug-0.log

npm install --no-audit --save @testing-library/jest-dom@^5.14.1 @testing-library/react@^13.0.0 @testing-library/user-event@^13.2.1 web-vitals@^2.1.0 failed
I use react version 19 and this erorr throw ,any other solution for this without --force or --legacy-peer-deps

This is a peer dependency issue. You are using React 19, but @testing-library/react@13.4.0 doesn't support it. You can either upgrade @testing-library/react to at least version 16.1.0 or downgrade to React 18.
Reference:
https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/releases/tag/v16.1.0

["I had the same error as you, but you can run the website using npm start. Make sure to cd into the correct path. Even though the page shows a red error, you can close it and proceed:

Press Ctrl + C to stop the current run.
Use the command npm install web-vitals.
Open the package.json file, and you’ll notice that "web-vitals": "^4.2.4" is not listed in the dependencies initially. After running the npm install web-vitals command, it will appear.

Then, run npm start again, and your project should be error-free. Hope this helps!"]1
enter image description here

Don't repost the same answer
